# -XIncoherentInstances doesn't work

Tags: haskell, ghc

I've been messing around with the [syntactic](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/syntactic) library (version 2.0 on github), and I have a small example that causes GHC(i) 7.6.2 to complain about `IncoherentInstances`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, 
TypeFamilies,
TypeOperators,
OverlappingInstances, 
UndecidableInstances,
GADTs,
FlexibleContexts,
IncoherentInstances #-}

import Data.Syntactic
import Data.Syntactic.Functional

type family FunToAST (dom :: * -> *) f
type instance FunToAST dom (Full a) = ASTF dom a
type instance FunToAST dom (a :-> fi) = ASTF dom a -> FunToAST dom fi

data Let a where
    Let :: Let (a :-> (a -> b) :-> Full b)

share :: (Let :<: dom,
          ApplySym sig fi dom, 
          SyntacticN (Denotation sig) fi, 
          fi ~ FunToAST dom sig)
          => Denotation sig
share = sugarSym Let
```

Fine. I'm *not* asking why I need `IncoherentInstances`. The problem is, when I include that extension, I get the exact same error message:

```
Overlapping instances for SyntacticN
                            (Denotation sig)
                            (ASTF sup0 a0 -> ASTF sup0 (a0 -> b0) -> 
                            ASTF sup0 b0)
  arising from a use of `sugarSym'
Matching instances:
  instance [overlap ok] (Syntactic f, Domain f ~ sym,
                         fi ~ AST sym (Full (Internal f))) =>
                        SyntacticN f fi
    -- Defined in `Data.Syntactic.Sugar'
  instance [overlap ok] (Syntactic a, Domain a ~ sym,
                         ia ~ Internal a, SyntacticN f fi) =>
                        SyntacticN (a -> f) (AST sym (Full ia) -> fi)
    -- Defined in `Data.Syntactic.Sugar'
(The choice depends on the instantiation of `sig, sup0, a0, b0'
 To pick the first instance above, use -XIncoherentInstances
 when compiling the other instance declarations)
In the expression: sugarSym Let
In an equation for `share2': share2 = sugarSym Let
```

I doubt this problem is actually related to the library, but I don't know enough about `IncoherentInstances` to write my own example.

Comment: Hmm, upon closer inspection of the error, is it telling me to use `-XIncoherentInstances` in the module where the instances are defined? That's part of the library, so I can't do that! Is there some other way around this?

Comment: `sugarSym Let` has the inferred type `(Let :<: sup, SyntacticN (Denotation sig) (ASTF sup a -> ASTF sup (a -> b) -> ASTF sup b)) => Denotation sig`. Why do you want to give it a different, less specific type?

Comment: As a matter of fact, it *is* telling you to use `IncoherentInstances` where the instances are defined.

Comment: @user2407038 I'm trying to remove any constraints on `a`, because they are preventing me from using `share` in `everywhereUp :: (forall a . ASTF sym a -> ASTF sym a) -> (forall a . ASTF sym a -> ASTF sym a)`. Of course, this is a totally different problem from my question.

Comment: @Carl Is this a way library devs can indicate "`IncoherentInstances` should *not* be used for these instances" (not that its ever really a good idea), or is simply an unnecessary restriction on their part?

Comment: @Eric It's more or less a side effect of the way the pragma works. Being able to overlap an instance (coherently or not) is metadata stored with the instance definition. This means you can use library-defined overlapping (or incoherent) instances without specifying the pragma in your own code, but it means that the instances must be declared to support overlapping.

Comment: @Carl That'd make a great answer.

Comment: @user2407038 I'm interested how you found that. When I type `sugarSym Let` into GHC(i), I get the error above, so I was trying to add constraints to disambiguate the instance.

Comment: @Eric The exact inferred type that I get when I compile your code and remove the type signature is `(Let :<: sup, SyntacticN f (ASTF sup a -> ASTF sup (a -> b) -> ASTF sup b)) => f`. This is with ghc-7.6.3 and syntactic-2.0, and with ghc-7.8.2 and syntactic-1.12.1.

Comment: @user2407038 I just copied and pasted my code, and removed the signature and got the incoherent instances error. Bizarre. That's with syntactic-2.0 and GHC 7.6.2, but I doubt that would make a difference... At any rate, getting that inferred signature helped me figure out what I wanted.

Comment: @user2407038 I discovered our discrepancy: I was trying `let f = sugarSym Let; :t f` in GHCi. This fails, but `:t sugarSym Let` gives the inferred type you mentioned.