# Converting single-instance class to function

Tags: haskell, ghc

I wrote some toy code to demonstrate my problem:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds,
             PolyKinds,
             UndecidableInstances,
             ScopedTypeVariables,
             FlexibleInstances,
             TypeFamilies #-}

import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Proxy

main :: IO ()
main = print $ show $ sumTypeVals (Proxy :: Proxy 4)

class HasVal x where
  val :: Proxy x -> Int

instance (KnownNat nat) => HasVal (nat :: Nat) where
  val = fromIntegral . natVal

type family Div2 (x :: k) :: k
type instance Div2 4 = 2
type instance Div2 2 = 1
type instance Div2 1 = 0
type instance Div2 0 = 0

-- compute sum of all powers of two
class Sum x where
  sumTypeVals :: Proxy x -> Int

instance (HasVal x, Sum (Div2 x)) => Sum x where
  sumTypeVals y | val y == 0 = 0
  sumTypeVals (y::Proxy x) = (val y) + sumTypeVals (Proxy :: Proxy (Div2 x))
```

The code above compiles. The instance of `Sum` works for *any* type-number representation, not just `TypeLits`. The single instance suffices due to the cycle in `Div2`, and is more covnenient than using a second instance as a base case because:

1. We would need a new base-case instance for every kind of number representation you want to use (pattern matched on its concrete representation of 0, say)
2. These instances are trivial to write
3. They require `-XOverlappingInstances`.

A class with a single instance covering all possible cases feels an *awful* lot like a *function*. Here's my attempt at that conversion (this replaces the class/instance):

```
sumTypeVals :: (HasVal x) => Proxy x -> Int
sumTypeVals y | val y == 0 = 0
sumTypeVals (y::Proxy x) = (val y) + sumTypeVals (Proxy :: Proxy (Div2 x))
```

The hitch of course is the recursive call with a different type. GHC-7.8 (rightly) `cannot deduce (HasVal (Div2 x))`, which isn't a problem in the class/instance setting due to the recursive class constraint on the instance. Although it is not overly burdensome to write a single instance of a class, there are a couple of reasons that a function seems like the better solution:

1. Why write a method when a function will suffice (if indeed it will in this case)?
2. <strike>Using a class opens the door for someone using `-XIncoherentInstances` later and overriding my universal implementation.</strike> **EDIT**: If I don't use `IncoherentInstances` when defining the class, [no one else can either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23332255/xincoherentinstances-doesnt-work).

The question: Is there any way to convert the *method* `sumTypeVals` to a *function*?

The most obvious fix to me is to somehow convince GHC that `HasVal x => HasVal (Div2 x)` (an assumption I'm perfectly happy to make). However, I'm not aware of any way to do this. I tried closing the type family `Div2`, but that didn't seem to help with the deduction, though I felt it should. Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you managed to actually use `sumTypeVals` in the type class? I get "Context reduction stack overflow" when I use `:t` on it in ghci.

Comment: Ah, I see it does work when you actually call it with a concrete argument, e.g. `sumTypeVals (Proxy :: Proxy 4)`. That's a weird function!

Comment: @AndrewC I'm just trying to find the most concise way to do type-level arithmetic (such as summing powers of 2) that is polymorphic over the type/kind of the representation of those numbers. For example, I had been using Data.Reflection (kind `*`), but I'm also considering GHC.TypeLits (kind `Nat`) and Data.Natural.

Comment: Why don't you do addition at the type level too such as in http://lpaste.net/104546 ? Some day singletons might be able to generate SumTypeVals from a normal function.